# RadComboBox set number of items to display

Tags: telerik-combobox

Is there any way to specify the number of items to display for a RadComboBox dropdown?

I have seen there is a property to set the lookup window height, which sets the dropdown's height on popup, but nothing related to the number of items to be displayed at a time in the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a number of items when using [**`ShowMoreResultsBox`**](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-load-on-demand-showmoreresultsbox.html) mechanism which provides a clickable button on the drop-down list to retrieve more results when they exist.

The above link provides instructions and here is a screenshot:

---

[image]

---

Specifically, you will set the **`itemsPerRequest`** property to the value you need, which for the photo above was set to **`10`** and therefore populates the box that many items on it's initial request.